# Export Apk in VS Xamarin Failed

Tags: android, xamarin, apk, packaging

I tryed to export an apk on my pc but it doesn't extract it and gave my this massege

```
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2045-07-26) or after any future revocation date.
```

or gave my an apk that crashed and I dont know why.. note app work on debug mode

but when i tryed to Export it  on another pc it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

> No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped.
>   Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after
>   the signer certificate's expiration date (2045-07-26) or after any
>   future revocation date.

Known issue with Java 1.7.x and Xamarin, most people are just ignoring it and have not had any problems submitting to Google Play store.

Some people are creating sym-links to point to Java 1.6 and others are using workarounds like this hack on in .csproj:

http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2015/06/getting-rid-of-no-tsa-or-tsacert-is.html

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>my.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>secret store password</AndroidSigningStorePass>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>alias -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass>other password</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
</PropertyGroup>
```